# Editing array elements with angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am using angular-formly to create input screens and all works great as long as I have a **KEY** for each **VALUE**.

But i have a situation where the value is an object with an array in it . It is an industry standard so I can not change the 
field structure.

The parent Key is **GEOCODE** its value is **COORDINATES** (which is an array with **2 elements**)

I want to edit those 2 elements (longitude and Latitude). Is this doable or does formly need a KEY:VALUE to create and input which will allow editing of those values.

```
/* -- JSON DATA -- */       
[ 
  "fullname": "Glen Benson",

  /* this is the objext I am trying to edit coordinates elements */
  **

"geolocation": {
    "coordinates": [
      -94.467136,
      39.090707
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  }

**
] 

/* -- FORMLY CONTROLLER SNIPPET --*/
{
   "key": "fullname",
   "type": "input",
   "templateOptions": {
      "type": "text",
      "placeholder": "fullname"
   }
},

**{ 
   "key": "geocode.coordinates[0]",
   "type": "input",
   "templateOptions": {
      "type": "text",
      "placeholder": "geocode"
   }
}**
```

Comment: I mean, you could always parse the structure and convert it to your own structure that is flat key/value pairs for formly, and then convert it back before submitting back to server.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is with your `"key": "geocode.coordinates[0]"` is that not working? Please create an example using: http://help.angular-formly.com

Comment: any updates to yout issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value without having to name it some crazy thing.  It should work how you have it, but I mean, my God, that is ugly.

just set the defaultValue to the value of geolocation....

```
key: 'CoordinateX',
defaultValue: 'model.geocode.geolocation.coordinates[0]'
```

OR add a controller on it to get it

```
key: 'CoordinateX',
controller: function($scope) {
 $scope.model.CoordinateX = $scope.model.geocode.geolocation.coordinates[0];
}
```

then you can simply use CoordinateX or whatever else you want to name it.